# Why setAllowClickWhenDisabled is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, view

As the title mentioned, I start using this **setAllowClickWhenDisabled** in order to fulfill my own development requirement: which is able to click on a disabled view, to open up another activity

Requirement: The disabled/grayed out view should be **tappable** in order to proceed with next activity

This is the clicklistener I put inside the onCreateView

```
private fun setupStatusClickListeners() {
        Log.i(TAG, "setupStatusClickListeners: ")
        binding.myStatusToggle()?.apply {
            setOnReadOnlySwitchClickListener(object : OnReadOnlySwitchClickListener {
                override fun onReadOnlySwitchClick(p0: View?) {
                    openUnitStatusActivity()
                }
}
```

This is my onCreateView, as I set the `setAllowClickWhenDisabled` to true before setup the clicklisteners

```
fun onCreateView(fragment: CcLoginDetailsFragment) {
        if (!FeatureProvider.Feature.COMMAND_CENTRAL_LOGIN.supported) {
            return
        }
        commandCentralLoginPresenter.onViewCreated(fragment)
        viewModel.setupBanner(activity.application)

        binding.myStatusProgress()?.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.unitId()?.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.myStatusToggle()?.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.unitIdOtherDetails()?.visibility = View.GONE

        binding.myStatusToggle()?.apply {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                Log.i(TAG, "setupStatusClickListeners2: ")
                binding.myStatusToggle()?.setAllowClickWhenDisabled(true)
            }
        }
        setupStatusClickListeners()
    }
```

and this is where the view getting disabled/grayed out, after some flag checking, came into this method and I'm making the isEnabled = false

```
if (viewModel.isSecondaryStatusSupported.value) {
    //some stuff
    binding.myStatusToggle()?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding.myStatusProgress()?.visibility = View.GONE
    binding.myStatusToggle()?.isEnabled = false
    //other stuff
}
```

This is my xml for this custom view

```
<com.motorolasolutions.uiframework.ReadOnlySwitchView
        android:id="@+id/viewStatusOnDutyToggle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:auto_toggle="false"
        app:text_primary="@string/title_my_status"
        app:text_secondary="@string/status_off_duty" />
```

I already set the **setAllowClickWhenDisabled** to true but I still unable to click on it (the disabled view) to open up another activity

This attribute is introduced in API31, my app is 33 as you can see, I wrap it with SDK checking over there

According to the description, it should work but the reality is totally opposite result

I wonder what could be wrong? or is that some overlapping view happening?

Comment: Your app targeting API 33 but how about your phone, is it running Android 13 yet?

Comment: You wrapped it in API version check, so your device is below Android 13 and nothing happened. You need to find other options than relying on this new method

Comment: yes my device is already at Android 13

Comment: Are you using view binding, and where do you create your `binding` object? It's a strange thing that you have to use `binding.myStatusToggle()` method to retrieve your view with a nullable `?.` check. I wonder if that `binding.myStatusToggle()` call return null in `onCreateView` or not

Comment: @TamHuynh yes am using view binding. 
Did you mean the binding.myStatusToggle() could be returning null here? I thought is just a safe null check

Comment: ViewBinding gets the view by field, not by method. How can you call `binding.myStatusToggle()` method and the project still can be built? I always use it like this: `binding.myStatusToggle` without the method bracket

Comment: This document about ViewBinding just said it, binding get the View by field, and no worry of nullable check: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#findviewbyid. But you need to debug your case to see if it's null or not